# How to disable the iPhone app on a testing device from apple developer member account

Tags: iphone, ios

How to disable an iPhone app running on a testing device without deleting it, for which the ipa file has been generated using a provisioning profile for the testing device. Assume I have access to the paid member account.

If I make the profile invalid, Does the app still works on the device ?

I am naive to the  iPhone development. I am sorry If my question is improper one.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that when you make a IPA with a profile from the provisioning center, it comes embeded within the IPA. So, theoretically, if you remove a device from the provisioning center, the change will not reflect on previously installed devices.

*Just a guess.*

If that's right, the only way I see to do it dynamically, is if you make by yourself an auth system for the app testers, requiring a password or whatever that will be validated online for the app be able to run.

Answer (score 0):

in apple developer provisioning center, when you make a profile, it asks you to select devices for that profile from your list. app will run on listed devices only, you can remove/add the devices by modifying that profile and then downloading profile and making a IPA with that profile.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is is it possible to remotely disable / wipe an app that you have previously sent to a tester.

I believe that is impossible, because assuming the tester managed to make it run at least one, he/she already has the provisioning profile and the app to match that provisioning profile. Therefore unless the tester changes that setup, there is nothing you can do to revoke the access.

On the other hand, I believe remote wipe is possible under the enterprise developer programme though.